# operation on determinant using different properties

Tags: determinant

Prove that
$\begin{vmatrix}
(b+c)^2 & ba & ac\\
ba & (c+a)^2 & cb\\
ca & cb & (a+b)^2
\end{vmatrix}=2abc(a+b+c)^3$

I tried my best for approaching the RHS but it gave no result.

**Can anyone please help me out**

Comment: Would you be content with a "brute force approach" (i.e. fully expand both sides) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

\begin{align*}
 \begin{vmatrix}
(b+c)^2 & ba & ac\\
ba & (c+a)^2 & cb\\
ca & cb & (a+b)^2
\end{vmatrix}&=\begin{vmatrix}
(b+c)^2+a(b+c) & ba & ac\\
b(c+a)+(c+a)^2 & (c+a)^2 & cb\\
c(a+b)+(a+b)^2 & cb & (a+b)^2
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=(a+b+c)\begin{vmatrix}
b+c & ba & ac\\
c+a & (c+a)^2 & cb\\
a+b & cb & (a+b)^2
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align*}

$\begin{vmatrix}
b+c & ba & ac\\
c+a & (c+a)^2 & cb\\
a+b & cb & (a+b)^2
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
2a+2b+2c & b(c+a)+(c+a)^2 & c(a+b)+(a+b)^2\\
c+a & (c+a)^2 & cb\\
a+b & cb & (a+b)^2
\end{vmatrix}$

Comment: I tried in this way but didn't get the required answer

Comment: @HariAnIndian One more step. Hope it helps now

Comment: Thanks for your assistant.